# Is it possible to change the battery in a 54604 light brick?

Tags: piece-information, repair, electronics, battery

I got 4 of these in in a bulk lot of Lego, but the lamp is getting quite dim in a couple of them.

Is it possible to change the battery in a [54604](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=54604) light brick?

[image: Electric, Light Brick 2 x 4 with Red LED]

It looks like the brick should open, but I don't want to force one apart and break it.

Comment: Either a part is screwed somehow, either you are.

Comment: You could also use a [heavy brick](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/123) instead of a light brick, there is no battery to replace.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's a YouTube video which explains how you can replace the battery in that light brick.

You can also find [the owner's explanation](http://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=37693) on the [Eurobricks](http://www.eurobricks.com/) forums.

Quoting from that site:

> What you'll need:
>
> - ExoForce Light brick (obviously)
> - A small screwdriver (or other item with a long, thin shaft) (my s'driver was 2mm (0.07 inches) thick)
> - A small 3V battery.
>
>   1. Put the point of the screwdriver into the hole in the brick (where you'd normally put the fiber optics cord).
>   2. Using quite some force, lever the screwdriver until the 'lid' pops up at the front.
>   3. Insert the screwdriver into one of the small gaps at the side where the 'lid' pops up, and lever the lid up again.
>   4. the lid should come right off. From here, you can shake the brick and the battery should fall out. Simply slide the new battery in and
>        click the lid back on.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed to know. I've taken the liberty of pasting the info from that site into your answer to mitigate against potential link-rot.

Comment: That's very wise, hopefully I'll learn to do it myself one day.

Answer (score 7):

Taken from the additional notes of this bricks [Bricklink catalogue entry](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=54604).

> This item takes one CR927 3V Lithium battery.
>
> A very tiny flat
>   screwdriver is needed to push the little clips to open up the
>   assembly.

I occasionally use the minifig-scale [Axe](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=3835), [Crowbar](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=92585) or [Screwdriver](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=6246a) to pry plates, tiles and other bricks. If you don't have a screwdriver of your own it might be possible to use one of these utensils to unscrew the casing depending on how tightley screwed in place your brick is.

This doesn't apply to bulk LEGO purchases, but in some cases LEGO sets will include instructions on how to replace the battery.

Comment: I did check one of the instruction books for an Exo-Force set that used one of these bricks, and it didn't include details of how to change the battery (e.g. http://cache.lego.com/bigdownloads/buildinginstructions/4499765.pdf)

Comment: It's shown in the [Winter Toy Shop instructions](http://cache.lego.com/bigdownloads/buildinginstructions/4616181.pdf), albeit a different type of light brick.

Comment: @Ambo100: I checked the instructions for several sets that include the brick, but there was nothing about the battery. And the I completely missed that on the Bricklink page. I promise I'll look more carefully next time!

Comment: Not to worry. I presume it's something they've added since 2006 when Power Functions were released.

Comment: Yep, the Winter Toy/Post Office and the Lighthouse all use a different brick and include instructions for using a key/screwdriver type thing to open them. These Exo-force ones apparently didn't. The "Minifigure with real torch/lightsabre" also don't include instructions for replacing the battery in the minifig's body.