# What would be a simple trebuchet design at the Minifigure scale?

Tags: building, design

I would like to have a trebuchet design at the Minifigure scale and simple enough for kids 10+ to build.

[image]

Note 1: The counter weight can be any non-LEGO heavy object.

Note 2: On top of the standard LEGO bricks, we have a lot of LEGO Technics and my kids are using them all the time. So, Technics are OK in the design.

Comment: I assume you're happy with a non-LEGO weight? Most elements are quite light unless you've got a few [weight bricks](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/123/56) lying around?

Comment: @Zhaph-BenDuguid Good point. I'm adding this to the question. Thanks!

Comment: Does it need to be functional?

Comment: Just as a bit of information, minifig scale isn't terribly restrictive as a trebuchet can be relatively massive compared to people. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Trebuchet_at_Warwick_Castle,_2009.jpg

Comment: @jncraton That's right. That gives more freedom for your design.

Comment: @Joubarc Off course it needs to work.  We have a castle to attack.

Comment: @Ambo100 No specific problem. I could build one and I could also design one for my kids.  I'm looking for other design(s) and (most probably) get really good ideas out of them. My kids and I will build 4 or more and it would be cool to have different ones.

Comment: I occasionally use the rubber wheel tires for small weights. They work pretty well if you need something kinda heavy. I don't know if you want to use them 'cause they don't exactly look super pretty...

Comment: If you don't need to worry about aesthetics, you could also use a small battery box

Comment: The set [Knight's Stronghold](http://guide.lugnet.com/set/6059) includes a functioning, if dinky, trebuchet.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a number of designs on the net that I found with a simple search. Google image search produces images from the merely functional ones like the [instructions](http://www.instructables.com/id/All-Lego-Trebuchet/) [linked](http://www.evilmadscientist.com/2007/build-a-lego-trebuchet/) [here](http://www.cryogenius.com/treb/) through to quite realistic looking ones that appear likely to work.

[image: Lego Trebuchet]

[or this big one](http://www.mocpages.com/moc.php/73257)

[image: big Lego Trebuchet]

The key for a simple, easy to build one is to use wheels on the base. It will shake back and forth when fired which means the structure does not need to be as strong. If you don't do that then the base will need to be similar in size to the arm, as in both pictures above. I am a little surprised that there's so little bracing on the arms of these models, as you can make a much stronger model using a tension member at least on the top of the arm, if not below.

But with Lego the main issue will be the density of the weight. Lego doesn't do high density part, so most people use non-Lego weights. Since you're willing to do that it's easy - the first picture shown has a lead weight, which is why it's hard to see that there's a weight at all.

Comment: You could probably still pull off an official-pieces counterweight with the right size battery piece; there are several in Lego's history that are rather hefty and would adequately fill that role, and many of the physics training aid sets I've seen include them for the purposes of training motor-based construction functions.